# Generate weekdays from today and a week forward

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm generating divs for each day of the week:

```js
var days = new Array("SUN","MON","TUE","WED","THU","FRI","SAT"); 

function generateWeekdays() {
  var d = new Date();
  var weekday = d.getDay();
  var todaysWeekday = days[weekday];

  for (var i = weekday; i < days.length; i++) {
      $('<div>' + days[i] + '</div>').appendTo('#weekdayList');

  }
}


 generateWeekdays();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="weekdayList"></div>
```

This generate (for example) today Wednesday and to Saturday (last index), but how can I make it generate one week, so it generates all the way to Wednesday the next week and stops after that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the module operator `%` to keep the indexes in bounds. This will make anything beyond the length of the array loop back so you can just go from 0 to the the array length add today's day to it:

```js
var days = new Array("SUN","MON","TUE","WED","THU","FRI","SAT"); 

function generateWeekdays() {
  var d = new Date();
  var weekday = d.getDay();

  for (var i = 0; i < days.length; i++) {
     console.log(days[(i + weekday) % days.length])

  }
}
generateWeekdays()
```

It's not completely clear in the question but if you want to include *next* Wednesday, you can loop with `for (var i = 0; i < days.length + 1; i++)`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of stopping at days.length, you can iterate for 7 (as you want for a week) times, and do a modulo (% 7) operation to get the element from days array.

```
var days = new Array("SUN","MON","TUE","WED","THU","FRI","SAT"); 

function generateWeekdays() {
  var d = new Date();
  var weekday = d.getDay();
  var todaysWeekday = days[weekday];

  for (var d = weekday, i = 0; i < 7; d++, i++) {
      $('<div>' + days[d % 7] + '</div>').appendTo('#weekdayList');

  }
}

generateWeekdays();
```

Answer (score 1):

How about cutting the days (from normal week days) and appending at the end (those days) for your week (that starts from today's day, you have to cut from there)

```js
function getWeekDaysFromToday() {
  let days = ["SUN","MON","TUE","WED","THU","FRI","SAT"];
  return days.concat( days.splice (0,new Date().getDay()));
}
console.log(getWeekDaysFromToday())
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `for` loop instead of iterating until `days.length` you want to just do 7 iterations and cycle back to the beginning of the array. If you set up a counter that will iterate 7 times and add an if statement in the loop to loop back to the beginning of the array if you reach the end, that should work.

Answer (score 0):

How about adding another iteration, to take into account of what today is in relation to the index of the array?

```js
var days = new Array("SUN","MON","TUE","WED","THU","FRI","SAT"); 

function generateWeekdays() {
  var d = new Date();
  var weekday = d.getDay();
  var todaysWeekday = days[weekday];

  for (var i = weekday; i < days.length; i++) {
      $('<div>' + days[i] + '</div>').appendTo('#weekdayList');

  }
  
  for(var i = 0; i < days.indexOf(days[weekday]); i++){
     $('<div>' + days[i] + '</div>').appendTo('#weekdayList');
  }
}


 generateWeekdays();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="weekdayList"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick implementation that I threw together. I used a do/while loop because you know you are always going to execute at least once. I Also limit the loop to the number of days you want to display so you could just increment that to show additional days. I also used the % (Modulus) with count and weekday to get the right value from the array.

```js
var days = new Array("SUN", "MON", "TUE", "WED", "THU", "FRI", "SAT");

function generateWeekdays() {
  var d = new Date();
  var weekday = d.getDay();
  var todaysWeekday = days[weekday];

  let count = 0;
  do {
    $('<div>' + days[(count + weekday) % days.length] + '</div>').appendTo('#weekdayList');

    count++;
  } while (count < 7)

}

generateWeekdays()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="weekdayList">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I took a different approach to the question.  Rather than checking incrementally if I have processed 7 days, I concatenated the days list to itself, so it would be 14 days, and then starting at the current day, I splice out 7 days so I have a week, and for each of them I create a div.

I also changed it to collect the divs and append them all at the end for some performance gains.

```js
var days = new Array("SUN","MON","TUE","WED","THU","FRI","SAT"); 

function generateWeekdays() {
  var oneWeekOfDays = days.concat(days).splice(new Date().getDay(), 7).map(function(day){
    return '<div>'+ day +'</div>';
  });
  
  $('#weekdayList').append(oneWeekOfDays);
}

generateWeekdays();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="weekdayList"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let dataArr = []; //empty array

let days = [
  "Sunday",
  "Monday",
  "Tuesday",
  "Wednesday",
  "Thursday",
  "Friday",
  "Saturday"
];

let d = new Date();
let weekday = d.getDay(); // it'll return day number like monday is 1


for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
  dataArr.push(days[(i + weekday) % days.length]); //push 7 days from today in array
}

console.log(dataArr)
```